# Microsoft Office Excel Interop Usage, Copy to local mode

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop

We are planning to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll in a windows service application to create excel reports.

The properties of the dll is set to "Copy to local" and "Embed Interop Types to false". This ensures the dll is placed in the bin folder where the binary is created.

But, my question is whether we can use "Copy to local" mode in an application. Will it violate any Microsoft license as the dll is part of Microsoft Office?

Please confirm.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming itself

Comment: To confirm, this question is related to programming with impact on the license.

Comment: You can try but that shouldn't work if you don't have a valid copy of Excel on your machine/server

Comment: There is to my knowledge no problem using this dll, as it's basically only a COM Proxy. The office license is "payed" by the Excel instance on the end user's computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been my experience that you`ll need Microsoft Office installed on the target computer to use the Interop. The Interop creates an Excel ActiveX object. That ActiveX object is not part of the Interop, but part of Microsoft Office. There`s no licence issues because the user had to purchase a license to install Microsoft Office.